# Getting last segment of url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to extract the last segment of URLs like this:

```
localhost:15043/Maintenance/ModelDetails/3?makeId=14
```

and this:

```
//localhost:15043/Maintenance/ModelDetails/3
```

I used below code, but this code does not work in this link:

```
localhost:15043/Maintenance/ModelDetails/3?makeId=14

var last_segment = window.location.hash.split('/').pop();
```

Comment: You stated in a comment below that `14` should be the result. Take more time when asking a question to provide clear descriptions of what the result should be in each situation. At this point, the question is very unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the pathname, search, and/or hash part of the `window.location` to do this. Ignore the parser here as it is just used as an example to run this code.

```js
var url = "http://localhost:15043/Maintenance/ModelDetails/3?blah=abc&makeId=14#test";
function parseUrl(url) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = url;
  return a;
}
var parser = parseUrl(url);
var last_segment = parser.pathname.split('/').pop();
var searchParams = parser.search.substring(1).split("&");
var lastParamValue = searchParams[searchParams.length-1].split("=")[1];
var hash = parser.hash;

console.log(last_segment);
console.log(lastParamValue);
console.log(hash);
```

Comment: Yes, I already noted that in my edit.

Comment: To make it output correctly, you should add a scheme to the URL. At least in Firefox, it gives blank results for the path and search.

Comment: @AliBayat OK, I was under the impression that you wanted the last URL segment which is 3 in this case. If you want 14, that would be the last search parameter value.

Comment: @AliBayat Updated.

Answer (score 3):

Won't this simple regex `.+\/` work for you with `replace()` ?

```js
var getLastSegment = function(url) {
    return url.replace(/.+\//, '');
};

console.log(getLastSegment("localhost:15043/Maintenance/ModelDetails/3?makeId=14"));

console.log(getLastSegment("//localhost:15043/Maintenance/ModelDetails/3"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **regexp** in your `.split()` method.

```
const pattern1 = /\?|\/|\&/;
const pattern2 = /\//;
const str = 'localhost:15043/Maintenance/ModelDetails/3?makeId=14';

console.log(str.split(pattern1).pop()); // return 'makeId=14'
console.log(str.split(pattern2).pop()); // return '3?makeId=14'
```

The `pattern1` will split the url on the `?`, `/` and `&` characters, and `pattern2` only on `/` character. So you can adjust the regexp to match with what you want.